# can I put 2 JPanels inside a JFrame like this?

Tags: java, layout, window, jframe, jpanel

would this put the two JPanels inside the JFrame or would I need to make a container of some sort?

I am just trying to get the JTextField to take up only 1 column above the buttons instead of being put in the column with all the buttons.

```
    window = new JFrame("Window");

    displayBox = new JTextField(20);
    display = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
    b0 = new JButton("0");
    b1 = new JButton("1");
    //...

    window.getContentPane().add(display);
    display.add(displayBox);

    window.getContentPane().add(buttons);
    buttons.add(b0);
    buttons.add(b1);
    //...

    window.pack();
    window.setSize(300, 400);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: `Window = new JFrame("Window");` please have a look at Java name conventions. It should be `window` and `display` and starting from capital letter

Comment: yea i fixed that i was just writing it really fast as an example. ty

Comment: Position of components in Java Swing is done using `Layouts`. [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: thank you figured it out from there for the most part. my top panel in the BoxLayout is way larger than it needs to be. however this question is answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change the code to

```
window = new JFrame("Window");
window.setLayout(new BoxLayout(window.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
window.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
window.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

displayBox = new JTextField(20);
display = new JPanel();

buttons = new JPanel();
buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));

b0 = new JButton("0");
b1 = new JButton("1");
//...

window.getContentPane().add(display);
display.add(displayBox);

window.getContentPane().add(buttons);
buttons.add(b0);
buttons.add(b1);
//...

window.pack();
window.setSize(300, 400);
window.setVisible(true);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

that should add the JPanels into the JFrame 1 ontop of the other.